# Load pagination on different component

Tags: php, joomla

I would like to load pagination module on different module than article. I have found that
 components\com_content\views\article\tmpl\default.php contains this:

```
<?php
if (!empty($this->item->pagination) && $this->item->pagination && $this->item->paginationposition && !$this->item->paginationrelative):
    echo $this->item->pagination;
?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

unfortunately if I put this code for example to my template index file it does not work. Aparently I have to add something more to this.

Could you advice me what other part of the code is needed? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's a little complicated to wrap your mind around but if you look in the `plugins/content` folder you will see the pagenavigation plugin. This is the plugin that creates the pagination you see in articles.

THis plugin is triggered by
`$results = $dispatcher->trigger('onContentBeforeDisplay', array('com_content.article', &$item, &$item->params, $offset));`

which you can find in `\components\com_content\views\article (and also archive and the tag view of com_tags).  I have no idea why it's not triggered in other components except at some point probably someone thought there wasn't a usecase for it.

To trigger the plugin in another component you would need to add that same event or a different event that basically does what the onContentBeforeDisplay method in the plugin does. If it is your own component I would do it in the same place content and tags do. If you need it in one of the core components you could probably do it by using another event.